# Implement mail sending system elegantly

Tags: c#, design-patterns, email

In my project I need to send emails. Emails will have different credentials and senders. I'm thinking about "abstract factory", but will it be good solution?

```
public abstract class Mail
    {
        public string Body { get; protected set; }
        public string Subject { get; private set; }
        public string EmailTo { get; private set; }

        protected Mail(string subject, string emailTo)
        {
            this.Subject = subject;
            this.EmailTo = emailTo;
        }

        protected abstract void BuildBody();
    }
public class AccountMail : Mail
    {
        private string _firstName;
        private string _lastName;
        private string _email;
        private string _siteDomain;
        public AccountMail(string subject, string emailTo, string firstName, string lastName, string siteDomain, string email): base(subject, emailTo)
        {
            _firstName = firstName;
            _lastName = lastName;
            _email = email;
            _siteDomain = siteDomain;
            BuildBody();            
        }

        protected override sealed void BuildBody()
        {   
             StringBuilder bodyBuilder = new StringBuilder();
             base.Body = bodyBuilder.ToString();
        }
```

That is abstract `Mail` and concrete `Mail`. Do I really need abstract `MailSender` and concrete `MailSender` for each email? This is quick solution, because I needed this functionality right now. It's working like this:

```
public abstract class MailSender
    {
        public abstract void SendMail(string subject, string emailTo, string firstName, string lastName);
    } 
public class AccountMailSender : MailSender
    {    
        public override void SendMail(string subject, string emailTo, string firstName, string lastName)
        {
            AccountMail mail = new AccountMail(subject, emailTo, firstName, lastName, "");
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage(ConfigSettings.EmailFrom, mail.EmailTo, mail.Subject, mail.Body);
                mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(ConfigSettings.EmailServer, ConfigSettings.EmailPort);
                client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(ConfigSettings.EmailUser, ConfigSettings.EmailPassword);

                try
                {
                    client.Send(mailMessage);
                }
                catch
                {

                }
            });

        }        
    }
```

I know that it's bad and that I need to refactor, but I also need your advice.

Comment: What are your test cases? Without having specific requirements it's difficult to implement anything. In the real world there are messages and there are services that send them. You build a message and pass it to a sending service. So I don't understand AccountMail at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Abstract base classes are only useful if you're inheriting functionality. So, what you've done with `Mail` is good, because all of your inheritors get their properties "for free". In contrast, there's no sense in your `MailSender` class. Inheritors get no functionality, but are forced to adhere to the contract you've decided on. That's what Interfaces are for.

What I actually don't like is that it's only possible to send an email to *exactly one* person with your classes. Very soon, you'll wish that you could send an email to a bunch of people at once. `EmailTo` should mimic the class that you're wrapping up and return a collection.

You're also missing any concept of `From` in your `Mail` class. I would expect an email message to know who it's coming from.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was thinking about interface and I've added it and then... remove. Don't know why. So, as far as I understand you, I'll do something like that SendMail(ISendMail sendMail)? Am I right?

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Comment: It's also generaly a good practice to dispose objects that implement `IDisposable`. In this case the `MailMessage` and the `SmtpClient`.